# Does Magus' sparkling targe only work on spells?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, magus

The Magus subclass 'Sparkling Targe' has the following abilty (emphasis mine), which increases your shields hardness when blocking:

> When you’re in Arcane Cascade stance with your shield raised, your
> circumstance bonus to AC from your shield also applies to your saves
> against spells and other magical effects. In addition, damage you take
> as a result of a spell or magical effect while you’re in Arcane
> Cascade can trigger your Shield Block reaction, even if the damage
> isn’t physical. **When blocking damage in this way**, increase your
> shield’s Hardness by an amount equal to the extra damage from Arcane
> Cascade [...] These benefits apply whether
> you’re using an actual shield, the shield spell, or something else
> that works like a shield [...]

What does "when blocking damage in this way" refer to exactly? Does it refer only to blocking spells, or to blocking damage in general? Does the hardness increase apply only to damage from spells or to damage blocked from any source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

The increased hardness given by the [Sparkling Targe](https://2e.aonprd.com/HybridStudies.aspx?ID=3) hybrid study only applies when using Shield Block against damage you take as a result of a spell or magical effect while you’re in Arcane Cascade.

"When blocking damage in this way" most reasonably applies to this new way to block, and would distinguish between the usual trigger of [Shield Block](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=839).

> **Trigger** While you have your shield raised, you would take damage from a physical attack.

Comment: I don't like this ruling, but I think it's correct. It's a bit of a stretch to say that "in this way" is referring *just* to using Shield Block while in Arcane Cascade stance but not the other stipulation in the same line haha

Comment: @ifusaso Exactly, the author is likely just saving words. Not seeing what else 'in this way' would refer to?? I mean, I guess they could have said 'when using Shield Block in a way that you could not normally...'

Comment: @brandon there are three stipulations for the Sparkling Targe ability... you *must* be in Arcane Cadence Stance, you *may* block magic effects, and you *do* use your reaction as a (modified) Shield Block. You gain the additional hardness when you block 'in this way' can only mean all three in the context given (as opposed to leaving out the allowance for magic effects).

Comment: I wasn't saying you were wrong, I was pointing out you were right even if I don't like the implications for shield magus

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't like this ruling either, but I suspected that this was the correct reading of the rules text. Which is unfortunate, because it makes this subclass way less appealing in my opinion.

Comment: I actually disagree it has to be read that way. "In this way" could just mean while in Arcane Cascade. I'll do an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: @Slaves_of_the_Coast You're of course free to rule it differently.